# Increment numbers within string using awk and sed

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed, hyperlink

I have a text file that has about 500 rows of information.

I am adding a few strings to the beginning of each line separated by a comma (Excel recognizes it as another column).

I have this code so far:

```
sed -e "2,$s@^@ =HYPERLINK(B2,C2), https://otrs.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=@"** C:\Users\hd\Desktop\newaction.txt > C:\Users\hd\Desktop\test.txt
```

I have a columns want. Once column is adding on a link to a previous column (easy enough)

Which will be a formula(string) in the first column is `=HYPERLINK(B2,C2)` and I want to increment the 2's to 3's,4's and so on.

Example:

---

```
=HYPERLINK(B2,C2)
```

---

```
=HYPERLINK(B3,C3)
```

---

```
=HYPERLINK(B4,C4)
```

---

```
=HYPERLINK(B5,C5)
```

---

```
=HYPERLINK(B6,C6)
```

It is my second day coding with sed and awk.

Is there any way I can make this happen using awk and sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN{$i = 2} s@^@=HYPERLINK(B${i},C${i})@; $i++" "input.txt"
```

will add `=HYPERLINK(B2,C2)` to the front of each line and increment the numbers each time.

Comment: Oh, I see! Might be a silly question but is there any way this can be done is just sed?

Comment: Ive been taking alot of notes so thanks for the help!

Comment: Np! It can be done in awk, not sure about sed. I'm most comfortable with perl and it has a lot of power for one-liners. Anything you can do in sed or awk you can do with perl.

Comment: Thats good to know. I might just start coding in Perl from now on!